# Register function raising a NameError when referencing the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to register various methods within a class using a registry function. This is the relevant parts of the code I have:

```py
class Quantity:

    _CONVERT_FUNCS = []

    def __register_conversion(func):
        Quantity._CONVERT_FUNCS.append(func)
        return func

    @__register_conversion
    def function1(a, b):
        return a + b

    @__register_conversion
    def function2(a, b):
        return a * b
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
    Quantity._CONVERT_FUNCS.append(func)
    ^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'Quantity' is not defined
```

How can I fix the auto registry for the functions?

Comment: Annotations are completely irrelevant to the problem you describe; nothing in the code that you show is an annotation; and this is not a [mre].

Comment: How do you raise this exception?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel is this better

Comment: Yes. The problem is that the decorator will call that `__register_conversion` function right away, while the class is still being created, but its logic wants to use the class, which has not been assigned to the `Quantity` name yet (because it is still being created). This is a common gotcha with classes.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel is there some workaround to this or should i just change my approach?

Comment: Simplest is to just use a global for the list.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you, that works! However, is this an acceptable practice to do when making a package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KarlKnechtel stated in the comments, using a global for the list fixes the problem. Here is the updated code:

```py
_CONVERT_FUNCS = []

class Quantity:

    def __register_conversion(func):
        _CONVERT_FUNCS.append(func)
        return func

    @__register_conversion
    def function1(a, b):
        return a + b

    @__register_conversion
    def function2(a, b):
        return a * b
```